# jQuery check if :checked on load

Tags: jquery

How would I be able to check to see if the checkbox is checked on pageload, if its checked then set the class to active?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNjzt/1/)

```
<label class="volume" for="mChatUseSound">click</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mChatUseSound" />

$('.volume').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
 });

.active{
   background:#FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Try `$(document).ready();` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  if($('#mChatUseSound').is(':checked')){
       $('.volume').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probably want something like this - passing in a condition to [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch) and triggering the event handler right away

```
$(function(){    
    $('#mChatUseSound').change(function(){
        $('.volume').toggleClass('active',this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YAZUE/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   //toggle can even unset the class    
   //dont use toggle
if($('#mChatUseSound').is(':checked')){
         $(this).addClass('active');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `switch` parameter of [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BNjzt/3/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.volume').toggleClass('active', $('#mChatUseSound').is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#mChatUseSound').is(':checked')){
        $('.volume').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```